# How to choose achitectures included in an Android app bundle?

Tags: android, gradle, abi

In our app, we have the following settings in build.gradle:

```
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
```

And:

```
    defaultConfig {
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
            }
        }
    }
```

However, when I build an app bundle, it includes x86 and x86_64 libs for Crashlytics and if I use **bundletool** to generate all the APKs from the bundle, I get x86 and x86_64 APKs. We don't want to support these architectures. How can I make it so the bundle will only include armv7 and armv8?

Answer (score 0):

`splits` is ignored for bundle, you should add:

```
bundle {
    abi {
        enableSplit = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, adding that doesn't seem to make any difference. The docs say it's true by default.